# Django mptt, category and subcategory system - Category has no field named 'parent'

Tags: django, django-mptt

I would like created category and subcategory system using django mptt.
My try:

```
from django.db import models
import mptt


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

mptt.register(Category, order_insertion_by=['name'])

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from xxxx.xxx.models import *
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin

admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

**My error:**

Category has no field named 'parent'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-mptt requires field with name parent with ForeignKey('self')

http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/models.html#setting-up-a-django-model-for-mptt

You can overwrite that with:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['name']
        parent_attr = 'category'
```